# Remove Quick Launch panel for the list view.aspx

Tags: list, view

I have a listview called customerListView which is located in 
http://sitename/customerList/customerListView.aspx. What would I need to do in order 
to hide the quick launch just for this listview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that customerListView.aspx is a web part page, you can add a Content Editor Web Part on that page and add following as content of that web part.

```
<style type="text/css"> 
  body #s4-leftpanel { display: none; } 
  .s4-ca { margin-left: 0px; } 
</style>
```

This is documented in several blog posts on the internet.